# Is this complex set open and connected

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Is the complex set $\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0$, $|z-2|>3$ an open and connected set?

Comment: Yes, it is. Can you prove that the set $\{z:\operatorname{Re} z>0\}$ is open, to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

- It is open, as it is the intersection of an open half-plane and the complement of a closed disk.
- It is connected, since it is  connected by arcs — you always can join two points by an arc, whether the line segment that joins them or an arc of circle concentric with the circle  $\lvert z-2\rvert =3$.